# Can I always set the first byte to 0x02 with the following implementation?

Tags: address, public-key, address-generation, java

I've followed [this](https://metamug.com/article/security/java-generate-bitcoin-wallet-address.html) tutorial on generating a Public Private key pair value and generating a valid Bitcoin address.
But one part makes me wonder if the implementation is done correctly which is the following:

```
ECPublicKey epub = (ECPublicKey) publicKey;
ECPoint pt = epub.getW();
byte[] pubBytes = new byte[33]; //32 + 1
pubBytes[0] = 2; //0x02
System.arraycopy(pt.getAffineX().toByteArray(), 0, pubBytes, 1, 32);
```

To me it seems like hardcoding the 0x02 could lead to errors when the last byte of the Y coordinate is odd or am I wrong?

If this implementation does prove to be wrong, how could I implement it correctly?

Comment: In addition to that bug, Java `BigInteger.toByteArray()` slightly more than half the time won't be 32 bytes as needed here. That looks like a good website to stay very far away from.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have checked that and for me, ```toByteArray()``` has consistently returned 32 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that the first byte should be `0x03` if the y-coordinate of the public key is odd. So indeed, the tutorial is not correct. If the y-coordinate is odd, just set this instead:

```
pubBytes[0] = 3;
```

It is worth noting, though, that you can simply negate the private key to achieve an even y-coordinate. This is obvious because if `[s]G = Y` then `[-s]G = -Y`. So it isn't really an issue if you did make this mistake and then wanted to fix it later. This was used in [BIP-340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki) to make all public keys 32-bytes instead of 33, by omitting the `0x02`/`0x03` and always assuming the even y-coordinate.

Comment: thank you for this confirmation
I have adapted my code like this ```pubBytes[0] = pt.getAffineY().mod(new BigInteger("2")).equals(BigInteger.ZERO) ? (byte) 2 : (byte) 3;```